# Taking user input, adding it to array at the correct index (ascending order)

Tags: c, arrays, input

I'm slightly confused as to how to get this to work properly. I need to take in numbers from a user (until they enter a negative or they hit the max size) and for each number they add, insert it into the correct index in ascending order. Right now, for some reason my array is limitless even though I defined a constant of 10. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 10
int addToArray(int *arr, int, int );

int main(){
    int array [MAX_SIZE];   
    int userNum = 0;
    int arrSize = 0;
    int add = 0;

    printf("Please enter a series of positive integers!\n");
    while(userNum >= 0 && arrSize< MAX_SIZE)
    {
        scanf("%d", &userNum);
        add = addToArray(array, arrSize , userNum); 
    }   

    return 0;
}

int addToArray(int *arr, int size, int num)
{
    int i, temp;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(num > arr[i+1])
        {
            temp =  num;
            num = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    arr[size++];
    return size;
}
```

edit1: yes I am unsure if the addToArray function works, if anyone could help me to get it to work that would be awesome!

edit2:I can't sort the array after the integers are inputted. THey need to be put in the correct index as the user is inputting them

Comment: Delete the `add` variable. Instead of `add = addToArray...` you want `arrSize = addToArray...` That will fix the *limitless* problem, but I'm not convinced that the `addToArray` function works.

Comment: `arr[size++];` is incomplete. It looks either as if you intended to set the element value, or, you expect that to increase the array length.

Comment: Your test `if(num > arr[i+1])` should be `if(num < arr[i])` otherwise it will insert, say, 5 between 3 and 4. I suggest you figure it out on paper before tinkering with the function, to see exactly how you want it to work (including edge cases).

Comment: your arrSize variable is not increasing it always equal to 0, in main function. I think that is the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 10

int addToArray(int *arr, int, int );

int main(void){
    int array[MAX_SIZE];
    int userNum = 0;
    int arrSize = 0;

    printf("Please enter a series of positive integers!\n");
    while(arrSize< MAX_SIZE){
        if(1 != scanf("%d", &userNum) || userNum < 0)
            break;//Invalid input is not used
        arrSize = addToArray(array, arrSize , userNum);//update arrSize
    }

#if DEBUG
    //check print for debug
    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    puts("");
#endif

    return 0;
}

int addToArray(int *arr, int size, int num){
    int i, temp = num;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(temp < arr[i]){//insert point
            num = temp;
            temp =  arr[i];//temp as new insert value
            arr[i] = num;
        }
    }
    arr[size++] = temp;

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rephrasing the question for my understanding.
You want to take an input of integers and sort them in ascending order.

If yes then you can use the code below. I have modified your code, there were a few errors. You can move the sorting part to another function for simplicity.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 10
int addToArray(int *arr, int, int );
int main(){
    int array [MAX_SIZE];
    int i=0,j=0,num=0;
    printf("Please enter a series of positive integers!\n");
    for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++)
    {
        printf("Before sort:Array[%d]=%d\n",i,array[i]);
    }
   /*sorting array*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < MAX_SIZE; ++j)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[j])
            {
                num =  array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = num;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++)
    {
        printf("After sort:Array[%d]=%d\n",i,array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this does work, but I can't insert all the integers and THEN sort. The integers need to be inserted in the correct order as the user in inputting them